# Borrar registro en Firebase usando Curl desde PHP

Tags: php, firebase, curl

Con este código inserto registro en Firebase:

```
$data = '{"ID":"1", "Nombre":"Aitana", "Edad":"0"}'; 
$url = "https://prueba-mirutasupersecreta.firebaseio.com/datos.json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if( curl_errno($ch) ){
    echo 'Error:'.curl_errno($ch);
}else{
    echo "Ya se grabó " . date('h:i:s A');
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Y todo bien, inserta, si cambio el id y ejecuto varias veces inserto varios registros y se ven así:
[image: Captura de Firebase]

Ahora, lo que quiero es borrar 1 solo registro, pero no encuentro como hacerlo, con este otro código donde lo que quiero es borrar el segundo registro:

```
$data = '{"ID":"2"}';  
$url = "https://mirutasupersecreta.firebaseio.com/datos.json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if( curl_errno($ch) ){
    echo 'Error:'.curl_errno($ch);
}else{
    echo "Ya se borro";
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

No se borra el segundo registro sino que se borra todo. Si cambio $data a esto:
$data = '{-M4_VB4cYmjwy_1042DJ}';

Pasa lo mismo se borra todo. Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Les comento que modifique el código de esta manera

```
$url = "https://mirutasupersecreta.firebaseio.com/datos/-M4fMQuhb2x2ntv9p1Hx.json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
etc etc
```

Donde como puede ver mando en el enlace el id y quito data y allí si me borra el registro. Sin embargo no se si es la forma correcta dado que tendría un tema para eliminar muchos registros y tendría que iterar haciendo ciclos repetitivos... no se si es la forma correcta. Gracias